# Notepad++ adds '\ufeff0' to the beginning of some files making it unable to merge

Tags: python, encoding, notepad++

I have loads of *.txt files that I read collecting data. Inadvertedly, I opened some of them with Notepad++ to see what the separators were. In doing this, I know that Noepad++ included a  '\ufeff0' to the file.

That in turn, makes reading the data impossible because it transforms a first character to  '\ufeff0'.

So, when I want to merge the files using a common column a get an error. For example, the columns I was supposed to merge contains the following:

```
temp1.month.unique()
array(['\ufeff0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11',
   '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', ... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...], dtype=object)
```

Thus, I cannot transform the numbers into string and merge, because of that first character.

Earlier, I had already set the settings of Notepad++ to Encoding with BOM.

Comment: `0xFEFF` is `BOM`, try converting it to encoding without `BOM` and see if the issue is resolved. I think the option is in the `edit` menu.

Comment: I just changed the setting to `Encoding in UTF-8`. But, the '\ufeff0' remained there.

Comment: I think your file is already encoded with BOM, you need to click `Convert to UTF-8`, as opposed to `Encode in UTF-8` to remove it.